# How to access click event of option in React dual list box?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, bootstrap-duallistbox

I am using [react-dual-listbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dual-listbox). Here I am able to select the columns and deselect and use the selected values. But, I want to access the selected option in selected items on click of that particular item. 
Ex: if 2 options are selected. If i click on second one, It should give me the value and index of the selected option. I saw something to use selectedRef for that purpose, But I am new to React.  
Could anyone please help me out.

```
<DualListBox 
            canFilter
            preserveSelectOrder 
            options={this.state.availableColumns}
            selected={selectedColumns}
            onClick={this.selectedRef}
            onChange={this.onColumnSelected}
          />
```